# SeekBar does not trigger onProgressChanged

Tags: android, seekbar

I am using SeekBar for my Feedback Dialog in Android.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feedbackview, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.seekHospitality));

    SeekBar hospitalitySeek = (SeekBar) layout.findViewById(
            R.id.seekHospitality);
    hospitalitySeek.setProgress(5);
    hospitalitySeek
            .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                        int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    if (seekBar.getId() == R.id.seekHospitality) {
                        TextView valHospitality = (TextView) getFeedbackDialog()
                                .findViewById(R.id.valHospitality);
                        valHospitality.setText(progress);

                    }
                }
            });
```

But when I change the SeekBar's progress, listener never triggers. Why?

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with not creating or setting the listener on the UI thread. What is the context of this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that:

```
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feedbackview, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.seekHospitality));
```

Here seekHospitality is not the root. So I change it and now it works.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I dun know whether you have tried adding debug message in OnProgressChanged but you can try replacing

```
    valHospitality.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
```

with

```
    valHospitality.setText(progress);
```

Comment: Thank you, I also tried. But the problem is, SeekBar doesn't trigger the OnProgressChanged event.

Comment: I tried with your SeekBar code from line 3 - **SeekBar hospitalitySeek = (SeekBar) layout.findViewById(R.id.seekHospitality);** and OnProgressChanged get called thus there may be other problems in your code. :(